# Can't get the drop down open

Tags: angular

I'm following the Udemy course on angular. I added a dropdown directive as below

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector:'[appdropdown]'
})
export class DropDownDirective
{
@HostBinding('class.open') isOpen=false;

@HostListener('click') dropdownClick()
{
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
}
}
```

And Added it to the declarations array in the AppModule. When I add it to the div in the app-recipe-detail component, when I click on the button, I don't get the drop down open

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="btn-group" appdropdown>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" >
            Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">To List</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Edit Recipe</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Delete Recipe</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out what's missing.

Comment: It should work, check if `bootstrap.js` referenced on page or not?

Comment: Yes I do have reference to jquery, popper.js and bootstrap.js